# Implement private chat using firebase

Tags: php, html, firebase

I am trying to implement private chat app (website) using firebase,but i will stuck with the private message logic.
Here is my code but its only for group chat not private

```
var messagesRef = new Firebase('https://sample.firebaseio.com/users');
var message="Hi firebase"
var userid="1"
//send message
 messagesRef.push({userid:userid, message:message});

//list the messages
messagesRef.limitToLast(10).on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
   //get the chat messages
    var data = snapshot.val();
    var username = data.name;
    var message = data.text;
    shomessage.append("from:"+username+"msg:"+message);
}
```

Suppose i have two users A and B(each user have an unique id) will be in private chat what is the changes in the above code??

**Note**:I didn't like to use firechat api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no one answer but here's a few basic options:

The structure

```
Users
  user_id_0
    messages
      message_id_0
        from: user_id_1
        message: "Hello to user_id_0"
  user_id_1
    messages
      message_id_1
        from: user_id_0
        message: "Hello back to user_id_1"
```

user_id_0 and user_id_1 would be observing their own messages node for added messages.

You could flip the logic and store data in a messages node

```
Messages
  user_id_0
    message_id_0
      from: user_id_1
      message: "Hello to user_id_0"
  user_id_1
    message_id_1
      from: user_id_0
      message: "Hello to user_id_1"
  public
    message_id_3
      from: user_id_0
      message: "Hello to the public"
```

You could even go really shallow and lean on logic within the code to be notified of changes but only show the user the ones that are private to that user and public messages.

```
Messages
  message_id_0
    from: user_id_0
    to:   user_id_1
    type: "private"
    message: "a private message"
  message_id_1
    from: user_id_0
    type: "public"
    message: "a public message"
```

Hopefully one of those will fit your model.

Comment: I'm new to firebase and would like to know if any documentation available for p2p chat it will be great! Thanks

Comment: @ShashankShah Yes, you can make a p2p chat with Firebase. Please start with the Firebase Getting Started guide and work through that. Once you have a better understanding of Firebase, you can see how it would work for a chat app.